# discord.py music bot: Bot doesn't return to queue after finishing the first song

Tags: discord.py

I did everything but couldn't get the bot to play the second song on the queue. When bot finishes the first song, it stops. I have to add another song to queue in order to get the bot to play the second song. How can i make it auto?

Code:

```
queue=[]


@commands.command()
async def play(self,ctx,message):
    if len(queue) <=5 :
            if r"https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=(\S{11})" is message:
                queue.append(message)
                await ctx.reply(message+" added to queue. ")

            else:
                keyword=(message)
                print(keyword)
                htmlurl="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + str(keyword)
                html=(urllib.request.urlopen(htmlurl))
                pattern=(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})")
                video_ids=re.findall(pattern, html.read().decode())
                print(video_ids, ".")
                urlh=("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+video_ids[0])
                print(urlh)
                
                queue.append(urlh)
                await ctx.reply(urlh+" added to queue ")
                    
    else:
        await ctx.send("Queue is full. Limit: 5 videos.")
        return
    
    for oyn in range(len(queue)):
        if ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            return
        else:
            FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'options':'-vn', 'before_options':'-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5'}
            YDL_OPTIONS = {"format":"bestaudio",'cachedir': False}
            vc = ctx.voice_client
            await ctx.send(queue[0]+" is now playing. ✨")
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(queue[0], download= False)
                url2 = info["formats"][0]["url"]
                source= await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)
            del(queue[0])
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*). Also, please include any debugging details: why does it stop? How are you running the commands? See [ask] for more information.

Comment: This is misuse of the for loop. You should be doing `for song in queue:` which removes your need to shuffle things around and continually deleting the first element of the list (which is extremely slow). Also, as TheFungusAmongUs mentioned, try to cut down on your code sample a bit until you get a small block that still can reproduce the problem.